# Troubleshooting acute latency of Akamai CDN

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, isp, cdn

Since yesterday I cannot load a number of web-sites which all seem to depend on Akamai CDNs. Not affected web-sites work fine, no problems with speed or anything.

The web-sites I cannot load are:

- www.spiegel.de
- www.facebook.com
- www.linkedin.com
- www.ebay.de
- www.amazon.de

If I look into the Network panel of the Dev Tools then it becomes apparent that the issues are related to CDNs. I am listing a small selection of CDN-URLs which are lagging - one URL per case.

- `http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-668350-hpcolumnright-qdcx.jpg`
- `https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/ym/r/Wgh7Dplbxhi.js`
- `http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/icon/icon_bullet_grey2_4x4.png`
- `http://rtm.ebaystatic.com/0/RTMS/Image/MERC-Electronics_HP_Flyouts_Q313-Explore-550x270.jpg`
- `http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/navbarCSSDE-beacon/navbarCSSDE-beacon-min-957729118._V1_.css`

Now if I ping the listed domains this is what I get:

```
raffael@raffael-GT60 ~> ping cdn1.spiegel.de
PING a1983.g.akamai.net (92.226.0.216) 56(84) bytes of data.

raffael@raffael-GT60 ~> ping fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net
PING a1168.dsw4.akamai.net (92.226.0.214) 56(84) bytes of data.

raffael@raffael-GT60 ~> ping s.c.lnkd.licdn.com
PING a1111.g.akamai.net (92.226.0.215) 56(84) bytes of data.

raffael@raffael-GT60 ~> ping rtm.ebaystatic.com
PING a1166.g.akamai.net (92.226.0.207) 56(84) bytes of data.

raffael@raffael-GT60 ~> ping z-ecx.images-amazon.com
PING a1248.g.akamai.net (92.226.0.215) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

And that is about it - the ping is stuck at the one line - so the ping does not come back.
Apparently though it is not a DNS issue as the domain is resolved.

As CDNs are location-aware I share with you that I am based in Munich, Germany - using O2 as ISP and my IP was a minute ago 92.229.240.223. Furthermore I use Ubuntu 13.10 but the problem is also handicapping my Windows 7 computer.

**How could I narrow down and investigate what is going on and maybe even resolve the issue or at least come up with a provisional solution?**

---

## UPDATE:

Traceroute result for IP of cdn1.spiegel.de:

```
raffael@raffael-GT60 ~> traceroute 92.226.0.214
traceroute to 92.226.0.214 (92.226.0.214), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  o2.box (192.168.1.1)  6.701 ms  17.272 ms  22.302 ms
 2  * * *
 ...
30  * * *
```

---

## UPDATE #2:

A friend of mine who lives in a town very close to Munich pinged some of the domains for me and he gets different IPs for the CDN hosts back as expected - given that he is not experiencing any problems:

F.x. a ping to cdn1.spiegel.de leads to IP 85.183.195.131 and a ping to s.c.lnkd.licdn.com leads to IP 85.183.195.115. Those IPs I can also ping without any problems.

What I find odd is that there is no outcry on Twitter yet - given that people cannot use those sites - which leads me to assuming that the problem is somewhat specific to my situation and does not affect just all of Munich.

---

(A verified provisional solution is to virtually relocate myself via Tor.)

Comment: What happens when you traceroute to the lagging IP. Does it show a routing loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as changing from my ISP's DNS to Google's by editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and replacing

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

with

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;
```

A reboot later the the change is done and can be confirmed by:

```
nmcli dev list iface wlan0 | grep IP4
```

cdn1.spiegel.de is now resolved to IP 2.16.216.113.

Further details on Google's DNS may be found [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).